# import users from 7 to 8 without drush

Tags: 8, migrations

I've been asked to import users from a drupal 7 site into an already-built drupal 8 site. I also need their order history from drupal commerce.

I tried using `drush migrate-upgrade --config-only` to do this, but as of drush 9, the migrate-upgrade etc commands don't work. There is a bug report about this and several patches, but my understanding of drush isn't advanced enough to properly patch & test.

Is there a way this can be done without needing to use drush?

Comment: Have you tried drush 8? 9 is still in beta and not ready for prime time yet

Comment: Don't you need Drush 9 at a certain release version of Drupal 8?

Comment: @Kevin according to the installation docs yeah, but in reality drush 8 still works fine for Drupal 8.5.0 at least

Comment: @Clive my Drush 8 broke after upgrading to 8.5.0, you most of done some sort of extra step to fix it.

Comment: Don’t think so @NoSssweat, for various reasons I actually downgraded my system drush to 8 the other day and tested it with a stock install of 8.5.0 and it seemed to work fine (at least for cache clearing and enabling/disabling modules, don’t think I tested anything else). Maybe you’re suffering from the local v global drush hell that’s plaguing people at the moment

Comment: @Clive I also noticed there is also a bug with 8.5.0 where when you do `drush --version` it says `9.2.0` even though Drush 8 is installed.

Comment: Mine also broke when I updated a project to 8.5.0 and Drush 8.

Comment: @Clive thanks, I had thought drush 9 was required for drupal 8 but if it's a possibility I'll look at downgrading and giving it a shot. Actually my drush broke too after attempting to upgrade drupal... then that broke and I had to restore from a backup. Seems the current state is pretty brittle.

Comment: @jammy yeah me too, then someone told me it was fine and I tried it and it seemed to be, but if others are reporting it’s not maybe my tests were too brief/trivial with 8.5.0. It’s not just you, everyone’s struggling with this at the moment. Even Acquia and Pantheon barely support their own platforms at the moment, I’ve had senior engineers from both telling me there’s nothing to do but wait!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way this can be done without needing to use drush?

If you create a custom module with a migration group you don't need to run `drush migrate-upgrade --config-only`, but if you screw up, you'll have to uninstall and re-install, a bit annoying.

> I also need their order history from drupal commerce.

Custom migration is the way to go.

Comment: thanks. I don't think I'm at a level yet where I could write a custom module for this unfortunately - but I'll look into the possibility.